# Oozie to Trigger a MapReduce Main Class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, oozie

Instead of setting up the job driver configurations , such as Inputformat mapper class etc in the oozie work flow xml, I want o to call my ExampleDecision.java. ExampleDecision  main method would take care of Job Set Up and configurations. How to do that ?

Would **II Java-Main Action decision nodes** illustration in [OOZIE_COOK_BOOK](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Java+Cookbook) 
be equal to `java ExampleDecision <strings...>`  and submit the job as a normal java job

or

would it be equal to `Hadoop jar SomeJar.ExampleDecision <strings...>`

Comment: Yes. You need to define a java action for calling your driver class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can very well create a map/reduce code using Java in which the main class takes  care of configuring the job and job dispatch as usual.

Then you may use the `java` action tag in the Oozie workflow to invoke the Main class in the Jar.

Here the Main class will dispatch the map/reduce job, which will be identical to the approach where you use the `map-reduce` tag.

The main consideration you have to assert is that you should only use the `job.waitForCompletion(true)` statement in the Main class to dispatch the job.

The important reason for this is to hold the Oozie execution on the Java action node until the map/reduce job dispatched by the Main class gets completed.

Edit:-

The differences between calling `hadoop jar` and `java jar` will be

- `hadoop` command would arrange few env properties beforehand to the
  mapreduce job execution like JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_HOME,HADOOP_OPTS etc.
  Mostly you might have already defined in your environment variables
  and this would not cause any problem while you execute using `java`
  command.
- While you use `java` action to invoke mapreduce job using Oozie workflow, Oozie will not be able to collect statistics,counters regarding the dispatched mapreduce job since the actual mr job will be spawned from the container dispatched for the `java action`.

So the `Java action node` executed by the Oozie will be running in a separate container(MapTask), which is just the Driver class which prepares the job and waits until the job gets completed, by then Oozie workflow also would wait to get the `java action MapTask` completed. You will be able to see the job id of the spawned mapreduce job from the `Oozie -info` command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, Java Action Tag.. would be equivalent to a Hadoop invoked MR Job,
ie          ~=  Usage: hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] [String Args]
NOT   ! ~=  Usage: java  [mainClass] [String Args]

Comment: Yes correct... In this case Oozie will arrange all env related settings for the job  as similar as hadoop command does..

Comment: Caveat: if you want specific properties for the parent Java Action (e.g. more RAM than its child mappers, or a different queue) then you must use the *very badly documented* prefix `oozie.launcher.` for each specific prop.

Comment: Wouldnt the JAVA ACTION NODE trigger it as normal Java Code , equivalent to JAVA <ClassName> instead of Hadoop Jar ClassName ?

Wouldnt this map reduce Job be called from a single MapTask ?,
Is there any way to access the control of executions to edge node ?